# Popup containing selectable items, submit to update partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a map page where the user can select multiple items to display on the map. I already got the map working with google maps javascript api but it only shows one item at a time based on the id in the url.

I am open to suggestions, but I am thinking the user should be able to open a popup or combobox which contains a list of items. Multiple items can be selected and when the user clicks ok, the selected items are passed into a partial view containing the map.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!!

Here are some bits of code from other parts of the site that might be helpful. I modified some of it to make sense in this context so I'm sorry if it's sloppy.

Popup window, could use this or some sort of combobox:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
 data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Select Assets</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /> All Assets
    @{ List<string> usedNodes = new List<string>(); }
    @foreach (var run in Model.Runs)
    {
        if (!usedNodes.Contains(run.NodeID))
        {
            if (run.GPS_Lattitude != zero && run.GPS_Longitude != zero)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" /> @run.NodeID
            }
            usedNodes.Add(run.NodeID);
        }
    }
</form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
            <button id="ok" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Popup script:

```
window.onload = function () {
    getMapMarkers();

    $('#cancel').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });

    $('#ok').on('click', function (e) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        getMapMarkers();
    });
}

function getMapMarkers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMarkers", "Map")',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { nodename: node, servername: server },
        success: function (???) {
            ???
        }
    });
}
```

Partial view change script, working great for selecting one item from a dropdown, but now I need to be able to select multiple items:

```
$('#assetSelect').change(function () {
    var assetId = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "@Url.Action("MapData", "Map")",
        data: {
            Id: assetId
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#partialMap').html(result);
            $('#partialMap').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Script for the select all checkbox seen in the popup window, does what it's supposed to, but it needs to become unchecked when you uncheck any other item:

```
$('#select_all').click(function () {
    var c = this.checked;
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', c);
});
```

Thanks again!

Comment: if you are doing this with `Google API` have you checked with their documentation.. if not have you tried a google search on Multiple Selection Map Coordinates Google Maps for example

Comment: yes, i have read through their documentation. the javascript api is more complicated than the others but I needed to use it for customizing. They seemed to be lacking an easy way to drop multiple pins at gps locations pulled from a function or database, I had to write my own function to create all the map markers and another one to calculate the center point.

Comment: so are you still having problems after writing your own.. sometimes there are no out of the box "Easy ways" of doing things in .NET in regards to web development thanks goodness for JavaScript

Comment: i will have no problem generating markers on the map in the partial view. where i'm having a hard time is making a popup box that passes a list of items (asset names) into the partial view.